# What is the proper syntax for making static function calls with Ethers.js version 6?

Tags: ethers.js

Without an official ethers.js 6.0 documentation we have to figure out the proper way to configure our code.

So far the following has worked for me to make static function calls:

```
await contract.buyTicket.staticCall(objectInformation.num, insurance, objectInformation.index, { value: precioBillete });
```

But I am detecting that it now fails to return the object with the `err.reason` in some projects.

Does anyone know the correct codification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm that this is the correct way to make static calls with the functions in version 6.0.

```
        await contract.excludeFromFee.staticCall(address, true);
```