Uniswap v3 QuoterV2 not returning amountOut
I have been trying to get a quote for two addresses using the Uniswap V3 QuoterV2 contract but I keep getting an error of:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'quoteExactInputSingle')

The Code:
const {
  abi: QuoterV2ABI,
} = require("@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/lens/QuoterV2.sol/QuoterV2.json");

const { ethers, AlchemyProvider } = require("ethers");

const WMATIC = "0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174";
const MATIC = "0xDA537104D6A5edd53c6fBba9A898708E465260b6";
const UNISWAP_QUOTERV2_ADDRESS = "0x61fFE014bA17989E743c5F6cB21bF9697530B21e";
const amount = ethers.parseUnits("1", "ether");

const provider = new AlchemyProvider("matic", process.env.POLYGON_PROVIDER_KEY);

const quoterv2 = new ethers.Contract(
  UNISWAP_QUOTERV2_ADDRESS,
  QuoterV2ABI,
  provider
);

const params = {
  tokenIn: WMATIC,
  tokenOut: MATIC,
  amountIn: amount,
  fee: 3000,
  sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0,
};

const main = async () => {
  const amountOut = await quoterv2.callStatic.quoteExactInputSingle(params);

  console.log(amountOut);
};

main();

If remove callStatic and run the code I get:
Error: contract runner does not support sending transactions (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.13.0)
code: 'UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION',
  operation: 'sendTransaction',
  shortMessage: 'contract runner does not support sending transactions'

After some googling I found this:
UniswapV3 Quoter throws error: contract runner does not support sending transactions (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION)
Someone said to connect the signer to the quoterV2 contract like so:
const amountOut = await quoterv2
    .connect(signer)
    .quoteExactInputSingle(params);

This results in the following error:
Error: execution reverted: "Unexpected error"

I believe this is suppose to happen but I do not see where the return value is. Unless I have to decode the data from the transaction? I am lost and could use a point in the right direction. I was look for the data that should be returned from QuoterV2.quoteExactInputSingle which should be
"outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "amountOut",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint160",
          "name": "sqrtPriceX96After",
          "type": "uint160"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint32",
          "name": "initializedTicksCrossed",
          "type": "uint32"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "gasEstimate",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],

The addresses do exist in the 0.3% the pool. The pool address is "0xf6Fc35E6bcaE4CA5b5948D348517EC9448AbD394" if you want to verify. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
NOTE: I am on the polygon POS network

The pool address 0xf6Fc35E6bcaE4CA5b5948D348517EC9448AbD394 that you mention has two completely different token addresses from your code.

Also the syntax in the first code block isn't correct, see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/154228/what-is-the-proper-syntax-for-making-static-function-calls-with-ethers-js-versio

Not really your question, but why!! is there such a thing as MATIC/WMATIC pool? WMATIC is simply a wrapped version of MATIC.

I got the pool address 0xf6Fc35E6bcaE4CA5b5948D348517EC9448AbD394 from
pool = await factory.getPool(tokenA, tokenB, fee)
as for the WMATIC/MATIC idk, I thought it was a pool lol

I switched the addresses to WETH/MATIC and now I'm getting the following error
Error: no matching fragment (operation="fragment", info={ "args": [ "0x7ceB23fD6bC0adD59E62ac25578270cFf1b9f619", "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010", 1000000000000000000, 3000, 0 ], "key": "quoteExactInputSingle" }, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.13.0)
amountOut = await quoter.quoteExactInputSingle.staticCall(tokenIn, tokenOut, amountIn, 3000, 0);

SOLUTION
Ethersjs v6 updated contract.callStatic.method to contract.method.staticCall(args...)
use this:
const amountOut = await quoterv2.quoteExactInputSingle.staticCall(params);
  

not this:
const amountOut = await quoterv2.callStatic.quoteExactInputSingle(params); 

The params for a Uniswap v3 QuoterV2 should look like the following
const params = {
  tokenIn: tokenInAddress,
  tokenOut: tokenOutAddress,
  amountIn: amount,
  fee: feePool,
  sqrtPriceLimitX96: something,
}; 

Ref: https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/contract/#BaseContractMethod-staticCall
Thanks @kfx!
